# How do I make the registration verification email send all user details?

Tags: administrator, emails, registration

The website requires administrator approval of users but I need the email to the admin to contain not just the name and email address of the new user but also all the other details in the login form.

I have this registration form and it looks like this: [image: registration form]

How do I make the auto-email send all these details? Where do I look?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You must edit file /components/com_user/models/registration.php line 549

```
$emailBodyAdmin = JText::sprintf(
    'COM_USERS_EMAIL_REGISTERED_NOTIFICATION_TO_ADMIN_BODY',
    $data['name'],
    $data['username'],
    $data['siteurl']
);
```

The template is on /languages/your-language/your-language.com_users.ini (ex: /languages/en-GB/en-GB.com_users.ini) seek for COM_USERS_EMAIL_REGISTERED_NOTIFICATION_TO_ADMIN_BODY define

```
COM_USERS_EMAIL_REGISTERED_NOTIFICATION_TO_ADMIN_BODY="Hello administrator, \n\nA new user '%s', username '%s', has registered at %s."
```

first $s is $data['name'], second $s is $data['username'], etc.

So, if you want to add password:

```
$emailBodyAdmin = JText::sprintf(
    'COM_USERS_EMAIL_REGISTERED_NOTIFICATION_TO_ADMIN_BODY',
    $data['name'],
    $data['username'],
    $data['siteurl'],
    $data['password_clear']
}
```

Then

```
COM_USERS_EMAIL_REGISTERED_NOTIFICATION_TO_ADMIN_BODY="Hello administrator, \n\nA new user '%s', username '%s', has registered at %s with password:%s."
```

You can also add all $data contents

```
foreach($data as $key=>$value) {
    $emailBodyAdmin .= $key." = ".$value."\n";
}
```

Or write custom $emailBodyAdmin field by field.

Comment: Thanks but...

It didn't work. I tried both. The first one doesn't change anything on the email. It still looks the same. The second one, all $data, gave me this: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_FOREACH in /hermes/bosnaweb17a/b1866/ipg.glenatgrandviewcom/joomla33/components/com_users/models/registration.php on line 523.

Comment: Any other way, please? I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: What is your joomla version?,

Comment: It's started with Joomla! 3.3 now it's Joomla! 3.4.7.

Comment: Consider that this may be a security risk as email is not a secure form of communication.  I would advise against this functionality and I turn it off by default in Joomla!